# Symfony: зачем нужна папка [Resource] в папке [app]

Tags: symfony

В Symfony — новичок...

---

В документации постоянно говорится, что:

> A bundle is simply a structured set of files within a directory

и тому подобное. То есть что бандл есть папка, в которой мы собираем все файлы бандла, тем самым держим всё в одном месте.

Если мы **сгененируем** новый бандл, оставив все значения по дефолту, то получим в папке `src` такую картину:

```
├── Acme
│   └── TestBundle
│       ├── AcmeTestBundle.php
│       ├── Controller
│       │   └── DefaultController.php
│       ├── Resources
│       │   ├── config
│       │   │   └── services.yml
│       │   └── views
│       │       └── Default
│       │           └── index.html.twig
│       └── Tests
│           └── Controller
│               └── DefaultControllerTest.php
```

---

Теперь сравним указанную картину с той, которая ставится при установке Symfony.

Папка `src`:

```
AppBundle
├── AppBundle.php
└── Controller
    └── DefaultController.php
```

Папка `app`:

```
└── Resources
    └── views
        ├── base.html.twig
        └── default
            └── index.html.twig
```

Здесь мы видим, что папка Resource находится в папке `app`.

Почему она здесь, а не в `AppBundle`?

Comment: Шаблоны в app/Resource можно использовать как общие для разных бандлов. Возможно поэтому решили туда всё добавить. Хотя ничто не мешает использовать шаблоны Бандла №1 из Бандла №2. Однако, в app/Resource можно переопределять шаблоны внутри любых бандлов. 

Если переопределение не требуется, то это скорей вопрос вкуса где размещать общие шаблоны. И если шаблон не общий, то лучше его держать внутри src/Acme/Bundle/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написано в [Symfony Best Practises](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations): `Store all your application's templates in app/Resources/views/ directory.`

Аргументируют они это тем, что названия шаблонов становятся меньше и так же для дизайнеров становится удобнее их искать и вообще все лежит в одном месте. В принципе это всего лишь "совет", и вы можете придерживаться классической структуры. В нашем проекте мы придерживаемся классическому расположению шаблонов и выносим все общие части в `app/Resources`. И пока никаких проблем не возникает.

И хотелось бы добавить, что в app/Resources можно переопределять шаблоны других бандлов, там им самое место.

Comment: Вы слишком узко смотрите на проблему. Дело вовсе не в путях к шаблонам, а в том, что приложение в целом по-сути не является чистым bundle'ом. Именно поэтому часть структуры приложения перемещается из AppBundle на уровень самого приложения.

Comment: Я не смотрю слишком узко на проблему и я понимаю что все созданные бандлы для проекта зависят от приложения и, в принципе, никогда из него не уйдут. И все их конфиги могут лежать в папке app/config/services.yml. Но как я говорил и раньше, что это рекомендация, и когда проект начинает разрастаться до 20+ бандлов, сложнейшей логики, приходится раскладывать все по полочкам и даже шаблоны

Comment: Я принимаю ваш ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел; однако отмечу, что я, к сожалению (а может и нет), перешёл на Yii2 в силу независящих от меня причин и сейчас некомпетентен в Symfony.

Comment: Эх, жаль что перешли на YII2, мы в нашем проекте работаем с SF3 и каждый раз она открывает перед нами новые возможности ))

Comment: По сравнению с Yii2? Или вы с Yii2 не работали? Просто Yii2 тоже ж не топором на коленке вырубался :); думаю, каждый фреймворк может чем-нибудь похвастаться. Хотя Symfony, когда я начинал его изучать, а потом начал изучать Yii2, мне больше понравился, но сейчас (спустя месяц), я чувствую себя более-менее свободно в Yii2, поэтому Symfony — может когда-нибудь ...

Comment: Обязательно вернитесь потом к Symfony, у нее очень правильный подход к разработке, и она очень гибка.